# How to disable ruby UDPSocket from resolving IP address on recvfrom?

Tags: ruby, sockets, ruby-1.8.7

When doing  data, addr = @socket.recvfrom(1500), the addr array contains Array: ["AF_INET", port, "resolved-name-or-ip", "ip"]

How can I disable resolving on UDPSocket? The documentation for ruby UDPSocket is bit poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found it.

I'll document this here so someone might get lucky and find it.

To disable automatic lookups, put this in your code:

```
BasicSocket.do_not_reverse_lookup = true
```

before you create the socket. It does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/UDPSocket.html), you can see in the `connect` method the `rsock_addrinfo` method called .

This method calls `getaddrinfo`.

So I don't see a work around, you have to call another connect method.

Maybe can you add some codelines for a better understanding? I'm afraid you can't.

```
static VALUE

udp_connect(sock, host, port)
VALUE sock, host, port;
{
rb_io_t *fptr;
struct udp_arg arg;
VALUE ret;

rb_secure(3);

arg.res = sock_addrinfo(host, port, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

GetOpenFile(sock, fptr);
arg.fd = fileno(fptr->f);
ret = rb_ensure(udp_connect_internal, (VALUE)&arg,
                RUBY_METHOD_FUNC(freeaddrinfo), (VALUE)arg.res);
if (!ret) rb_sys_fail("connect(2)");
return INT2FIX(0);
}
```

Source: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/socket/rdoc/UDPSocket.html

Comment: My bad, I forgot to put the ruby version :(, I'm using ruby 1.8.7